# Newton Divided Difference Method of Interpolation in maple

Tags: maple

Does anyone know how one can do this in maple?
find Newton divided difference interpolation polynomial for the function cos2x the points {1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.1, 0}

Comment: are mikham javabe akhar sade beshe.

Comment: age bekham ye evalf behehesh ezafe konam ke deghatesh beshe 4 ya 5 raghame ashar, koja bayad ezafe konam?

Comment: tnx faghat az darso emtehane fardatoon ja namoonin!

Comment: fek konam are  .

Comment: na dorost shod. mamnoon

Comment: are javabe akhar bedas omad

Comment: shabe shoma ham bekhair. emtehane khoobi dashte bashid va baz ham mamnoon

Comment: manam koli proje maple behem ezafe shod!!!! alan daram say mikonam antegral giri adadi be raveshe gaus ro bezanam!!!

Comment: che khoob :) vali man hanooz dargire tarife int be raveshe gausam! mohasebat adadia cheghad dardesar dare :|

Comment: help narmafzar ke hamechio nadare! to cd ke dashtam amoozesho dare ama inaee ke mikham nist

Comment: manzooram rahnamae cd nist! 11saat amoozeshe maple ro daram. tamame oon bakhshayi ke to pdfa hast ro dars mide. albate hanooz kamel nadidam

Comment: tamoom shod vali nemidoonam moshkelesh kojas! javab mideha vali javabesh ba pasokhe tamrin motefavete

Comment: javabo jaye 0.79 mizane 0.69

Comment: mohasebe adadi antegral be ravesh gaus bood javabi ke khode ketab dade boode be soal 0.79e vali narmafza0.69

Comment: na ketab ba khode formoolo rahhalesh rafte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is homework then you could show what you've accomplished on your own already.

If you just need the result then you could try the Student:-NumericalAnalysis package. Eg,

```
L:=[0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 1]:

p:=Student:-NumericalAnalysis:-PolynomialInterpolation(
               [seq([x,cos(2*x)], x in L)],
               method=newton):

Student:-NumericalAnalysis:-DividedDifferenceTable(p);

  [           1.              0              0             0             0]
  [                                                                       ]
  [ 0.9800665778  -0.1993342220              0             0             0]
  [                                                                       ]
  [ 0.8253356149  -0.7736548145   -1.914401975             0             0]
  [                                                                       ]
  [ 0.3623577545   -1.543259535   -1.539209441  0.6253208900             0]
  [                                                                       ]
  [-0.4161468365   -1.946261478  -0.5757170614   1.070547088  0.4452261980]


interpol:=Student:-NumericalAnalysis:-Interpolant(p,independentvar=x);

      interpol := 1. - 0.1993342220 x - 1.914401975 x (x - 0.1)

         + 0.6253208900 x (x - 0.1) (x - 0.3)

         + 0.4452261980 x (x - 0.1) (x - 0.3) (x - 0.6)

plots:-dualaxisplot(plot([cos(2*x),interpol],x=0..1),
                    plot([cos(2*x)-interpol],x=0..1,legend=`abs. error`));
```

[image]

Programming questions on Maple are often better asked on stackoverflow, unless your central question is about the mathematics behind the algorithm.